# Perfmon metrics collector error

Tags: java, jmeter

When I run the test, I got this error:

> 2017-07-01 18:21:14,752 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration.setFormatter(Ljava/text/DateFormat;)

I've tried this solution but it doesn't work
https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=ru#!topic/jmeter-plugins/5HFRZaH9suQ

I would be appreciated for any help.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a .jar clash, i.e. you have newer JMeter version and older PerfMon plugin or something like that.

The fastest and the easiest solution would be installing everything from scratch, steps are:

1. Download JMeter 3.2 (or later) from [JMeter Downloads](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page and unpack it somewhere
2. Download [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager) jar and drop it to the 'lib/ext' folder of your JMeter installation
3. Start JMeter
4. From JMeter's main menu choose `Options -> Plugins Manager`
5. Switch to `Available Plugins` tab and install `PerfMon (Servers Performance Monitoring)` and any other plugins

---

You can try fixing existing installation, in this case you will need to provide at least exact JMeter and any plugins versions and full contents of lib and lib/ext folders.

Answer (score 0):

setFormatter function exists in Jmeter 3.1 and not in Jmeter 3.2

Work with Jmeter 3.1 until a fix will be done to PerfMon plugin